# MVVM DataBinding & Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm, picasso

Щупал, так сказать, я паттерн MVVM сегодня, и наткнулся на неприятную проблему, вычитал что можно сделать **override** методов в xml через @BindingAdapter, и пытался загружать картинку через Picasso, но картинка не очень и хочет загружаться, может кто знает и подскажет, буду сильно благодарен

MainActivity:

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simplemvvm;

import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.danielstrelnikov.simplemvvm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    User user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        user = new User();
        binding.setUser(user);
    }

    public void addAge(View view) {
        user.setAge(1 + user.getAge());
    }


}
```

Класс User для удобной работы с MVVM:

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simplemvvm;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class User extends BaseObservable {

    @Bindable
    String name;

    @Bindable
    int age;

    @Bindable
    String url;

    public User(){
        name = "Daniil";
        age = 18;
        url = "https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/1/9/9/4926991.jpg";
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.age);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    public static void imageLoader(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Ну и само активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.danielstrelnikov.simplemvvm.User"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.name}"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(user.age)}"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addAge"
            android:text="+"/>
        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@{user.url}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Попробуй так @BindingAdapter("android:src") -> @BindingAdapter("app:image").

Comment: К сожалению нет, теперь еще и warning (Application namespace for attribute app:image will be ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто хотя-бы посмотрел, ребята не забывайте включать

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

в манифесте приложения, хоть **Picasso** и не напоминает об этом